VSCode extension display inline form on code editor
Im building a vscode extension where I would like to add some additional context to the code. To do this, I'm using Code Actions, which when clicked should bring up a form with two inputs and a submit button.
Below is an example on how this is done in github copilot extension.

I was able to add the Code Actions and the input text field. But this is different from the inline text that Github copilot has. This shows as a quick input.
How can i bring up a UI similar to what Github copilot extension has done?
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.languages.registerCodeActionsProvider('typescript', new AddContextCodeActionProvider(), {
            providedCodeActionKinds: AddContextCodeActionProvider.providedCodeActionKinds
        })
    );

    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.addContext', (line: number) => {
            showInlineForm(line);
        })
    );
}

class AddContextCodeActionProvider implements vscode.CodeActionProvider {
    static readonly providedCodeActionKinds = [
        vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix
    ];

    provideCodeActions(document: vscode.TextDocument, range: vscode.Range): vscode.CodeAction[] {
        const addContextAction = this.createAddContextAction(document, range);
        return [addContextAction];
    }

    private createAddContextAction(document: vscode.TextDocument, range: vscode.Range): vscode.CodeAction {
        const action = new vscode.CodeAction('Add Context', vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix);
        action.command = { command: 'extension.addContext', title: 'Add Context', arguments: [range.start.line] };
        return action;
    }
}

function showInlineForm(line: number) {
    const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if (!editor) {
        return;
    }

    const decorationType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
        after: {
            margin: '0 0 0 1rem',
            contentText: 'Add Context: ',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            color: 'blue',
            border: '1px solid blue',
            borderRadius: '3px',
            padding: '0 5px'
        }
    });

    const range = new vscode.Range(line, 0, line, 0);
    editor.setDecorations(decorationType, [range]);

    vscode.window.showInputBox({ prompt: 'Enter context' }).then(value => {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            editor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(line, 0), `// ${value}\n`);
            });
        }
        editor.setDecorations(decorationType, []);
    });
}


this Github extension is written by Microsoft and most likely uses some non-public API. Because it is a downloadable extension it uses the same loading method as extension you develop must use. You can analyze the source code of the Github extension how it does this "peek" window GUI. But don't trust that the next version of VSC this undocumented API still works

@rioV8 The source code of this extension is not available..

go to your extension folder and look for the copilot extension, the code is in there, maybe minified but you can search for the GUI strings, after reformatting
